# How easy is it for a user to remove files from NSLibraryDirectory?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ipad

I was wondering how easy it is to remove files from the NSLibraryDirectory?  I want to store some data there that I don't ever want to be removed from the device.  The files are big and I have tried to encrypt them, but it takes 30-60 seconds for the files to decrypt to be displayed on the iPad and this is just too long so I didn't want to encrypt them.

If anyone can tell me how hard it would be for someone to get these files off of the iPad or have another solution of how to protect them that would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of keeping this files on the device forever? Is there any reason why they shouldn't just be a part of your app bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each app has a sandbox that includes a Documents folder that you can use to organize and save resources. On a non-jailbroken device no other app will ever have access to that folder. This folder will be deleted if your app is removed from the device.

On a jailbroken device all bets are off unless you use encryption.